# Android build improper gradle version

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to build an android project from the command line.

I am following [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle-android/#scratch)

My project structure and files match the tutorial exactly.

When I run gradle build it tells me that version 2.2 of gradle is required, but I have a newer version of gradle installed, 2.10. So does that mean I must download an older version of gradle to build android?

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'GradleJavaApp'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 2.10. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in H:\GradleJavaApp\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.2-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use older version of Gradle! Stick to version 2.10 (or newer).

If you followed the tutorial thoroughly,
you probably used version 1.1.3 of Android build plugin:

```
buildscript {
    …
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
    }
}
```

Build plugin version 1.1.3 is terribly outdated from the view of Android development (released on March 2015 according to [the release notes](http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/gradle-plugin.html)).

Change that to the latest version 2.1.0. 
Gradle wrapper should then stop complaining about Gradle version and 
you should be able to use Gradle 2.10 normally.

Also replace all mentions of Gradle 2.3 in the tutorial with version 2.10.